# GlassFish JDBC Connection Pooling

Tags: java, odbc, connection-pooling, pool, jdbc-odbc

I am trying to make a connection pooling for my web application but don't know basics how to setup with sql server with it

Main questions: what is resource type (What to write), classname, driverclass name?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    String str="SELECT * from Book";
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:lol","Sar\\KILLER_GUY",null);
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(str);
            System.out.println("SalesPerson Id: ");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                String id= rs.getString("Add");
            System.out.println(id);
            }
            con.close();
        }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what're you trying to achieve. Do you want to create connection pool on your glassfish domain? Do you have any problems with this code? Have you tried to run this code in glassfish (how?)? Are you trying to connect to Sql Server or Oracle?

Comment: i want to create a connection pool on my glassfish domain , i dont have any problem with the code i want to learn how to create a connection pooling for java ee6

Comment: for practical my faculty told me to create a jdbc connection pooling for my web application using existing database in my sql server and i m jst learning the basic how to create jdbc pooling using my sql server completely blank what and how to do it

Comment: by `my sql server` do you mean your MS Sql Server or MySql server?

Comment: MS sql server i tagged my question wid odbc because i want a clearity can i do with odbc or nt?

Comment: Check out the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggndx.html#ggnfv

Comment: Not at all helpfull dont know how to begin with asadmin?

Comment: where to write asadmin ?

Comment: Well, have you tried to google this? Or just search in the same guide: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/giobi.html#scrolltoc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set up a connection pool in GlassFish, then access the connection pool data source via JNDI (Java Naming and Directory Interface - the Java API for directory services). See [this step by step tutorial](http://www.javaxt.com/Tutorials/Glassfish/How_to_set_up_a_Connection_Pool), which gives details of the following outline:

1. Open List of JDBC Connection Pools

   In the Glassfish admin panel, open the list of JDBC Connections Pools using the navigation menu on the left side of the page (Resources->JDBC->Connections Pools). In the JDBC Connections Pools, click New... to create a new JDBC Connection Pool.
2. Create a New JDBC Connection Pool

   In the New JDBC Connection Pool dialog, specify a name for the pool. Be sure to specify the correct "Resource Type" and click Next.
3. Specify Datasource Classname (**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource**)

   On the next page, specify the Datasource Classname. The class name is of course driver specific. Consult your driver documentation to find the right class . Click Finish to create the JDBC Connection Pool.
4. Edit the Connection Pool

   Once the JDBC Connection Pool has been created, you can go back and add/edit properties such as the JDBC Connection URL, username, password, etc.
5. Create a JDBC Resource

   Finally, you will need to create a new JDBC Resource (Resources->JDBC->JDBC Resources) that you can reference in your web application.
6. Create a Connection

   Once you have created a connection pool, you can use it in your web app (e.g. servlet or JSP) like this:

```
// Look up the connection pool data source
javax.naming.InitialContext ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource)ctx.lookup("Your JNDI Name here");

// Get a database connection
java.sql.Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
try {
  // Do something with the connection
} finally {
  // Close connection so it can be released back to the pool!
  conn.close();
}
```

Comment: gknicker: can u pls clearify what is jndi and jdbc connection pool?

Comment: I clarified JNDI in my answer. JDBC is Java Database Connectivity, and a JDBC connection pool is really just a JDBC DataSource that supplies pooled connections.